# 401 Unauthorised while retrieving keys from Key vault in API

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-rest-api

I want to know keys present in Azure Key Vault using API. Referred this document: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/get-keys/get-keys?tabs=HTTP)
Using this request to get bearer token in my PC:-

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=3aaf24aa-a918-442f-9973-7c056d3a79ae&client_secret=xxxx&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F.default' https://login.microsoftonline.com/811f967e-0856-4e36-92e3-60224639e39d/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

But calling API failing with 401 unauthorized message:
{
"error": {
"code": "Unauthorized",
"message": "AKV10022: Invalid audience. Expected https://vault.azure.net, found: https://management.azure.com."
}
}

Anyone faced similar issue and get success in listing keys from key vault using API.

PS:  I can get the keys in CLI and Powershell but I want same from API

CLI - `az keyvault key list --vault-name mykeyvault`

Powershell -  `Get-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName 'mykeyvault'`

Comment: You need to generate token with `https://vault.azure.net/.default` scope. Could you modify curl command to this: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=3aaf24aa-a918-442f-9973-7c056d3a79ae&client_secret=xxxx&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fvault.azure.net%2F.default' https://login.microsoftonline.com/811f967e-0856-4e36-92e3-60224639e39d/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: Thanks @Sridevi. Now, it's throwing different error: {"error": {"code": "Forbidden","message": "Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource.\r\nIf role assignments, deny assignments or role definitions were changed recently, please observe propagation time.}} Please help

Comment: Could you please confirm what access configuration you are using for key vault? Vault access policy or RBAC?

Comment: It's Role-based access control.

Comment: Then you need to grant Key Vault related RBAC role to your service principal under key vault.

Comment: Can post it as answer?

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error occurred as you are using **wrong** scope to generate the
> access token. To **resolve** the error, change scope to *https://vault.azure.net/.default*

In my case, I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permission** as below:

[image]

Make sure to grant proper RBAC role like **Key Vault Administrator** to the service principal under your key vault like this:

[image]

Now, I generated access token using below **curl** command by replacing scope:

```bash
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=appId&client_secret=secret&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fvault.azure.net%2F.default' https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to call API via Postman, I got **list of keys** successfully in response as below:

```
GET https://srikv23.vault.azure.net//keys?&api-version=7.4
```

**Response:**

[image]